# Comparing multiple regression coefficients of two populations

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I have two populations with three variables v1, v2 & v3 each. The variables are the same in both the populations and I have developed multiple linear regression models for the two populations with the specification v1 = f(v2, v3). The variances of the variables in the two populations are not necessarily the same and the size of two populations are quite different, one very large(around 700,000) and the other relatively small(about 50,000). Now I would like to compare how significant v3 is in the first population against v3 in the second population and in the presence of v2 in both the models. Is there any way I can do this by a formal statistical test ?

In my question above, by significance I mean how much more important is variable v3 of one population than the variable v3 of the other population in explaining the variation in the dependent variable v1.

Comment: Welcome to our site! I think for this question to be answerable you need to clarify what you mean by "how significant `v3` is" - do you mean more *statistically significant*, in the sense of how strong the evidence is for including `v3` in your model, or do you mean it in the everyday sense of the word "significance" to mean "importance" (in which case you are likely more interested in the magnitude of the two regression coefficients)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In my question above, by significance I mean how much more important is variable v3 of one population than the variable v3 of the other population in explaining the variation in the dependent variable v1.

Comment: It would be great if you could edit your question to clarify that. The "edit" button is at the bottom of the question. (I think the "In my question above, by significance I mean how much more important is variable v3 of one population than the variable v3 of the other population in explaining the variation in the dependent variable v1" is probably clear enough to copy straight into your question.)